# Can anyone help me in finding this integral? Without using differentiation under integral sign.

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Solve the integral
$I$ = $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$

Comment: See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506224/confirm-that-int-0-inftyt-1-sin-t-dt-pi-2/2506265#2506265

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277916/proving-int-mathbb-r-frac-sinxxdx-pi?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: G.H. Hardy wrote a paper with several methods of evaluating this integral.  See http://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/hardy/sinx/sinx.pdf